# How to match all unicode lowercase letters and all digits

Tags: python, unicode, python-re

Since the re module doesn't support a Perl re character class like [\p{Ll}\d] what would be the best way to implement this in Python 3.x? Note that the union of islower and isdigit seems to be larger.

Edit: to clarify: I wrote a static microblog generator in both Python and Perl (see: https://github.com/john-bokma/tumblelog ) and I want both to have the same functionality. I am in the process of adding tags e.g. https://plurrrr.com/tags/2021/python.html gives an overview of all entries tagged "python". I want to limit tags to lowercase letters and/or numbers separated by spaces (which I replace with '-'). To support other languages I want to use [\p{Ll}\d] which works in Perl.

Edit 2: I am going to check out pcre for Python.

Comment: Maybe [regex](https://pypi.org/project/regex/)?

Comment: Another way is to use a custom parser, for examble defined using [pyparsing](https://pypi.org/project/pyparsing/) which I know to support Unicode. But Unicode is weird, excluding uppercase glyphs from your inputs seems to me, without context, unnecessary complexity.

Comment: If you only want to accept lowercase letters, I would just force any input to all lowercase first, rather than trying to reject uppercase characters. Then you can probably use `\w` (which is equivalent to `[a-zA-Z0-9_]` when the ASCII flag is used), depending on your feelings about `_`.

Comment: It would be *nice* if `re` allowed POSIX character classes like `[:lower:]`; I'm not sure why it does not.